# Call the side_effect function each time the mock method is called instead of at the beginning?

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I need to mock an object with a bunch of methods. For all except one Mock() is perfect for me. But for one of the methods, I actually need to call a function whenever the method is called during the run.

Basically, I am doing some basic threading, so for my code to work, I can't give it the return values manually before the run. The function has to be called during the run.

```
m = Mock()
m.meth.side_effect = foo()
```

When I do this, as expected, it calls `foo()` at the start, and uses that value permanently

So, I would like it such that whenever during the run - `m.meth` is called - `foo()` is called (and value returned)

Comment: I am not sure understand your question. Try `m.meth.side_effect = foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you found the answer yet but you should just assign and not call the method as well.

```
m = Mock()
m.meth.side_effect = foo
```